# Seeking Mac Software Solution for Correcting Barrel Distortion

Tags: software, wide-angle, distortion

I have a Nikon D7000 and a 14-24 wide angle lens which I love, but it does result, often, in a great deal of barrel distortion.

I'm seeking a software solution; ideally an Aperture plug-in, to correct barrel distortion.

Note: I do not have Adobe Photoshop.

Comment: Are you sure that is the lens? The 14-24mm I've used showed nearly no barrel distortion. Due to its extremely wide-angle there is something people call geometric or perspective distortion but that has to do with the angle of view. On my case on a D3, so it won't be so pronounced on yours.

Comment: You are correct; my apologies.

Comment: Barrel distortion *is* a type of geometric distortion. It is not a type of perspective distortion. For more, please see [What is the difference between perspective distortion and barrel or pincushion distortion?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85526/15871)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PTLens](http://epaperpress.com/ptlens/) and [Bibble](http://bibblelabs.com/) can both do these, and both support MacOS. PTLens can be used as an Aperture plugin. I kind of doubt that Bibble can -- it's intended more as a direct competitor to Aperture than a plugin.

Both come with large databases of lenses and the corrections they need. Both also read the EXIF data to see what lens you were using (and in the case of a zoom, what focal length you had it set for) and automatically take that into account.

At a guess, PTLens is what you'd prefer -- and the price ($25) is hard to argue with as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) to do these types of corrections.

They also have a nice [guide for lens calibration](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/calibration/en.shtml), which allows you to calibrate for the distortion of your lens, then save those settings to apply later.

Answer (score 4):

It's not an Aperture plugin and it's probably not the answer you *want* to hear, but a quick search seems to indicate that there's an Adobe Lens Profile for this lens meaning that if you're using Lightroom 3 or Photoshop CS5, that'll take care of it.

Comment: +1, I'm upgraded to LR3 mostly for that, the new lens distortion correction modules. Really helpful for my 16-35mm on a full-frame.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at FishEye-Hemi:

https://imadio.com/products/prodpage_hemi.aspx

It's not built around correcting specific barrel distortion, but instead is built to correct wide-angle (not just fisheye) distortion in such a way that lines are straightened and people look good - so it tries to take aesthetics into account when correcting images.

They have a free trial download so you can see if you like the application, there are basically three different corrections to try so you can quickly see if it works for you.  It's available as a plugin for Aperture in addition to Photoshop and Lightroom.

When evaluating all of the software don't forget to look at the full-size image to make sure not too much data is dropped.