# Golden Ratio, Fibonacci Spiral, and other crop guides for Lightroom?

Tags: composition, lightroom-6, golden-ratio

When cropping in Lightroom it will helpfully overlay the image lines marking thirds, which makes it easy to crop using the Rule of Thirds.

Is there any plug-in/add-on or other means to instead overlay with lines marking the Golden Ratio, or with a Fibonacci Spiral?

Comment: Related: [How to use the Fibonacci spiral to create better photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/73732/15871) and [What kind of Compositional Elements are used in this pic?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/98142/15871) and [What is the 'Golden Ratio' and why is it better than the 'Rule of Thirds?'](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/8965/15871) and [If viewers don't respond to the rule of thirds, why do some photographers still emphasize it?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67807/15871)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LR has an option to cycle through the various grid overlays for cropping, including the Golden Ration, Fibonacci Spiral and others.

1. In the Develop module, select your photo.
2. Click on the "Crop" icon from the right-side panel (it's the first one on the left).
3. Press the letter "O" to cycle through the overlay options.  Or select in the `Tools >> Crop Guide Overlay` submenu.

For overlays that have different center points press Shift-O to cycle through those.